# What does #optional mean for a "details" form element?

Tags: forms, 8

The [node edit form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeForm.php/function/NodeForm%3A%3Aform/8.2.x) contains the following form element.

```
  $form['revision_information'] = array(
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#group' => 'advanced',
    '#title' => t('Revision information'),
    // Open by default when "Create new revision" is checked.
    '#open' => $node->isNewRevision(),
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('node-form-revision-information'),
    ),
    '#attached' => array(
      'library' => array('node/drupal.node'),
    ),
    '#weight' => 20,
    '#optional' => TRUE,
  );
```

What does the `#optional` property mean for it?

I looked at both the [`Details`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Details.php/class/Details/8.2.x) and the [`VerticalTabs`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21VerticalTabs.php/class/VerticalTabs/8.2.x) classes, but neither of them seems to handle that property.

What does setting `#optional` to `TRUE` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is handled in the render element `Details`. (See the *Details.php* file.)

```php
public static function preRenderDetails($element) {
  // Omissis
  // Do not render optional details elements if there are no children.
  if (isset($element['#parents'])) {
    $group = implode('][', $element['#parents']);
    if (!empty($element['#optional']) && !Element::getVisibleChildren($element['#groups'][$group])) {
      $element['#printed'] = TRUE;
    }
  }
  return $element;
}
```

If `#optional` is `TRUE` and there are no visible children, then the element is not rendered.

Comment: Do you have any idea, why these properties are not documented properly in each Render Element (e.g. [Details element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Details.php/class/Details/8.2.x))? How are users supposed to use them, they have to search in code and "resolve" written conditions?

Comment: @JurajNemec The description is manually added to the documentation comment for the class. It seems they forget to add all the properties used by a form o render element.

Comment: None of the Render Elements or Form Elements are documented properly. There is no comprehensive list properties for any of the elements. You have to look at the source code in many cases. They say that the properties documented on RenderElement are 'inherited' by all render elements, but that's not true; some will work, others will not, and even the ones that will work do not always produce the same results from element to element.